# is there any way to start node js server

Tags: node.js, api

I have created API using node js and my API is live now (in production) but now I always want to open Cpanel and terminal and run command to start node js API. but now I want like I just run one-time command in terminal and it will run automatically even in my computer is shutdown. or there is another way to do this because I google it but I found nothing.

Comment: What server you are using ?

Comment: Why don't you deploy it to a cloud server?

Comment: @xMayank we are using Linux dedicated server for.

Comment: @dhruvtailor our client purchased this server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a process manager like [PM2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/)

installation

```
npm install pm2
```

start your application

```
pm2 start server.js
```

use following script to check if your server is running or not

```
#!/bin/bash
ps cax | grep node > /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "Process is running." >/dev/null 2>&1
else
  echo "Process is not running."
  PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
  pm2 start /path/to/your/node/application
fi
```

setup this script as [cron job](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/74Docs/Cron+Jobs)

```
sh /path/to/your/script
```

[click here](https://www.assistancy.be/blog/keep-nodejs-running-shared-hosting) for script source and more info

Comment: no extension is required for bash, you can use .sh if you want, give it chmod +x script.sh to make it executable

Comment: bro is still not working today i try but doesn't work even script file not opening

Comment: are you getting any errors? please add more details

Comment: bro is working fine now thanks for your help...@ehmad